# Adding a Target for All UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uigesturerecognizer

I am working to integrate a current iOS application with an analytics suite.  One of analytics items that we will use in our UX analysis is a complete track of all gestures (at least ones that are recognized through a UIGestureRecognizer subclass).  My goal is to add this hook into the analytics suite without having to subclass each gesture recognizer.

My initial thought was to write a category that had an override for an existing method on UIGestureRecognizer, but I couldn't find a safe way to do that (and I also learned that there is no way to call the class's existing implementation of that method without method swizzling).

My next approach would be to use poseAs and simply have a subclass of UIGestureRecognizer pose as UIGestureRecognizer and add a target on init.  However, I then learned that poseAs is deprecated (and has been for a while), so I also abandoned this approach.

Obviously, I could subclass each gesture recognizer we are using, but I feel that doesn't take advantage of the dynamic nature of obj-c.

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: Class posing was declared deprecated with Mac OS X v10.5, and is unavailable in the 64-bit runtime.

Comment: Probably there's not a 'good' way to accomplish that. That's what people refer to as "aspect-oriented programming" I believe. You might be able to get some mileage out of  method_exchangeImplementations, but it's gonna be tricky. I don't even know if that works on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I don't think there is a clean way to do this.  I ended up subclassing all of the gesture recognizers to accomplish this shared functionality.